# C++: Rotating a vector around a certain point

Tags: c++, vector, rotation

I am trying to rotate a vector around a certain point on the vector(in C++):

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

rotated around the point (1,1) (which is the "5")  90 degrees would result in:

```
7 4 1
8 5 2
9 6 3
```

Right now I am using:

```
x = (x * cos(90)) - (y * sin(90))
y = (y * cos(90)) + (x * sin(90))
```

But I don't want it rotated around (0,0)

Comment: Post some C++ code illustrating what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The answer depends on your coordinate system.

### Computer graphics coordinate system, with `(0,0)` at *Top* left

If you are using a computer graphics vector implementation where `(0,0)` is the **top** left corner and you are rotating around the point `(dx, dy)`, then the rotation calculation, including the translation back into the original coordinate system, would be:

```
x_rotated =      ((x - dx) * cos(angle)) - ((dy - y) * sin(angle)) + dx
y_rotated = dy - ((dy - y) * cos(angle)) + ((x - dx) * sin(angle))
```

### Physics/Maths coordinate system, with `(0,0)` at *Bottom* left

If you are using a more traditional real world coordinate system, where `(0,0)` is the **bottom** left corner, then the rotation calculation, around the point `(dx, dy)` including the translation back into the original coordinate system, would be:

```
x_rotated = ((x - dx) * cos(angle)) - ((y - dy) * sin(angle)) + dx
y_rotated = ((x - dx) * sin(angle)) + ((y - dy) * cos(angle)) + dy
```

<sub>Thanks to [mmx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33708/mmx) for their comment on [Pesto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/620769/42473)'s post, and to [SkeletorFromEterenia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29075925/42473) for highlighting an error in my implementation.</sub>

Comment: Maybe silly question, but may top left system works with definition for bottom left? Maybe silly mental example, let say that I want rotate 9, 9 around 10, 10 by 45 degree. Now set expectations, 9,9 vs 10,10 have -45 degree. +45 rotation gave 0 between center and rotated vector, so I expect x= 10 y=10-length of vector. And "standard equations gave me this" with one thing, default rotation is counterclokwise, but here I work like it was clockwise. And finally question, can standard equations work for top left coordinate system with default rotation as clockwise?

Comment: You can write your software in such a way to handle multiple coordinate systems at the same time, but I would recommend against it @viceriel as it's far too easy to end up getting confused, and it expands your test data set enormously.

Answer (score 11):

The solution is to translate the vector to a coordinate system in which the center of rotation is (0,0). Apply the rotation matrix and translate the vector back to the original coordinate system.

```
dx = x of rotation center  
dy = y of rotation center

V2 = V - [dx, dy, 0]  
V3 = V2 * rotation matrix  
Result = V3 + [dx, dy, 0]
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using a standard vector implementation where (0,0) would be the top left corner and you're rotating around the point (x_origin, y_origin), this should do it:

```
x = ((x - x_origin) * cos(angle)) - ((y_origin - y) * sin(angle))
y = ((y_origin - y) * cos(angle)) - ((x - x_origin) * sin(angle))
```

Note that the y's are `y_origin - y` because the y value increases as you go down.

Comment: You'd need to translate it back after the transform. The resulting (x, y) is not in the original coordinate system.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer from Mark Booth to be wrong (rotate (0,1,0) by 0 degrees and you get (0,-1,0) with his formula), and I ended up with:

```
double cs = cos_deg(new_degrees);
double sn = sin_deg(new_degrees);

double translated_x = x - x_origin;
double translated_y = y - y_origin;
    
double result_x = translated_x * cs - translated_y * sn;
double result_y = translated_x * sn + translated_y * cs;
    
result_x += x_origin;
result_y += y_origin;
```

This can be further shortened of course, but I want to make it as simple as possible.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error, I've now updated [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/620769/42473) with a fix, and detailed how the coordinate system you are using means that you need a different solution to the one [Pesto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/620769/42473) proposed.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a [translation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_%28geometry%29) to move rotate about a different point.