# Rotating back points from a rotated image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, rotation

I’m having troubles with rotation.
What I want to do is this:

- Rotate an image
- Detect features on the rotated image (points)
- Rotate back the points so I can have the points coordinates corresponding to the initial image

I’m a bit stuck on the third step.

I manage to rotated the image with the following code:

```
cv::Mat M(2, 3, CV_32FC1);
cv::Point2f center((float)dst_img.rows / 2.0f, (float)dst_img.cols / 2.0f);
M = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(center, rotateAngle, 1.0);
cv::warpAffine(dst_img, rotated, M, cv::Size(rotated.cols, rotated.rows));
```

I try to rotate back the points with this code:

```
float xp = r.x * std::cos( PI * (-rotateAngle) / 180 ) - r.y * sin(PI * (rotateAngle) / 180);
float yp = r.x * sin(PI * (-rotateAngle) / 180) + r.y * cos(PI * (rotateAngle) / 180);
```

It is not to fare to be working but the points don’t go back well on the image. There is an offset.

Thank you for your help

Comment: why don't you try to rotate back your matrix with -rotate angle, getRotationMatrix(), and warp affine...

Comment: Why not just use an inverse matrix to the rotation matrix? Trigonometry sounds fragile to me.

Comment: Yes but how do I find back the points in the rotated matrix?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++: Rotating a vector around a certain point](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620745/c-rotating-a-vector-around-a-certain-point)

Answer (score 8):

If `M` is the rotation matrix you get from `cv::getRotationMatrix2D`, to rotate a `cv::Point p` with this matrix you can do this:

```
cv::Point result;
result.x = M.at<double>(0,0)*p.x + M.at<double>(0,1)*p.y + M.at<double>(0,2);
result.y = M.at<double>(1,0)*p.x + M.at<double>(1,1)*p.y + M.at<double>(1,2);
```

If you want to rotate a point back, generate the inverse matrix of `M` or use `cv::getRotationMatrix2D(center, -rotateAngle, scale)` to generate a matrix for reverse rotation.

Answer (score 3):

For a rotation matrix, its transpose is its inverse. So you can just do `M.t() * r` to move it back to your original frame, where `r` is a `cv::Mat` (you might have to convert it to a `cv::Mat` from a `cv::Point2f` or whatever, or just write out the matrix multiplication explicitly).

Here's the code to do it explicitly (should be correct, but warning, it's entirely untested):

```
cv::Point2f p;
p.x = M.at<float>(0, 0) * r.x + M.at<float>(1, 0) * r.y;
p.y = M.at<float>(0, 1) * r.x + M.at<float>(1, 1) * r.y;
// p contains r rotated back to the original frame.
```

Comment: I would like to use your code to do the matrix multiplication explicitly but I'm having a assertion error with the element access.

    `code`OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && data && (unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0]
    && (unsigned)(i1*DataType<_Tp>::channels) < (unsigned)(size.p[1]*channels()) && ((((sizeof(size_t)<<28)|0x8442211)
   >> ((DataType<_Tp>::depth) & ((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 15) == elemSize1()) 
    in unknown function, file C:\OpenCV2.2\include\opencv2/core/mat.hpp, line 517`code`

Comment: you formula misses translation from M

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

For a transform `M` and point `pp` in the rotated image, we wish to find the point `pp_org` in the coordanates of the original image. Use the following lines:

```
cv::Mat_<double> iM;
cv::invertAffineTransform(M, iM);
cv::Point2f pp_org = iM*pp;
```

Where the operator * in the above line is defined as:

```
cv::Point2f operator*(cv::Mat_<double> M, const cv::Point2f& p)
{ 
    cv::Mat_<double> src(3/*rows*/,1 /* cols */); 

    src(0,0)=p.x; 
    src(1,0)=p.y; 
    src(2,0)=1.0; 

    cv::Mat_<double> dst = M*src; //USE MATRIX ALGEBRA 
    return cv::Point2f(dst(0,0),dst(1,0)); 
}
```

**Note:** `M` is the rotation matrix you used to go from the original to the rotated image

Answer (score 0):

- You need to rotate your points accorning to center point of your image.
- Here x and y are your points which you want to rotate, imageCenter_x aand _y is center point of your image.
- Below is my code.

  ```
  angle = angle * (M_PI / 180);  
  float axis_x = x - imageCenter_x;  
  float axis_y = y - imageCenter_y;       

  x = axis_x * cos(angle) + axis_y * sin(angle);   
  y = (-axis_x) * sin(angle) + axis_y * cos(angle);

  x = x + imageCenter_x;  
  y = y + imageCenter_y;
  ```