# Points are reaching the origin point while rotation

Tags: c, math, rotation, geometry, coordinates

I am trying to rotate a rectangle using the matrix (x cos θ - y sin θ, x sin θ + y cos θ). The problem is that the rectangle is getting smal and reaching the origin point per time (I am using timer). Here is my code.

```
void WINAPI Rotate(POINT arr[5])
{
    static POINT origin = { 400, 400 };
    static int i;
    static const double angle = 0.1;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
            // translate
        arr[i].x -= origin.x;
        arr[i].y -= origin.y;
            // rotate
        arr[i].x = arr[i].x * cos(angle) - arr[i].y * sin(angle);
        arr[i].y = arr[i].x * sin(angle) + arr[i].y * cos(angle);
            // translate
        arr[i].x += origin.x;
        arr[i].y += origin.y;
    }
}
```

So I want the points in `arr` to be fixed distance from the origin point after rotation. I don't want them to reach the origin point per time.

Initially:

```
    arr[0].x = 200;
    arr[0].y = 100;
    arr[1].x = 100;
    arr[1].y = 100;
    arr[2].x = 100;
    arr[2].y = 200;
    arr[3].x = 200;
    arr[3].y = 200;
    arr[4].x = arr[0].x;
    arr[4].y = arr[0].y;
```

**If this is the wrong way for rotation, does someone know a correct method to rotate a rectangle about its origin, without affecting its size?**

Here are snapshots while it rotates:

[image] [image] [image]

Comment: what is the problem??? put the output? angle is in radians or degrees? do you keep that at mind? the code seems reasonable

Comment: It doesn't matter for angle. It is reaching the origin point per time and getting small until it disappears

Comment: What do you mean by "reaching the origin point per time"?

Comment: and for rectangular it is enough to use only 4 points!!!

Comment: Why 5 points anyway? For a rectangle 2 points are enough: upper right and lower left corner. Others you can calculate easy and fast.

Comment: @0x90 sorry. I use 5 points so that I can close the polyline.

Comment: @m0skit0 The rectangle is getting small and small while it is rotating until it disappears

Comment: @m0skit0 I have added the output

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/620745/c-rotating-a-vector-around-a-certain-point

Comment: @AdamLiss just for performance. because the function will be called many times by the timer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your rotation,

```
arr[i].x = arr[i].x * cos(angle) - arr[i].y * sin(angle);
arr[i].y = arr[i].x * sin(angle) + arr[i].y * cos(angle);
```

you use the *new* `x`-coordinate to compute the new `y`-coordinate, but you should use the old one. To fix it, use a temporary,

```
double temp = arr[i].x * cos(angle) - arr[i].y * sin(angle);
arr[i].y = arr[i].x * sin(angle) + arr[i].y * cos(angle);
arr[i].x = temp;
```

Comment: Nice catch, but the math is wrong!  :-)  Save `old_x` and use _that_ for the calculations.

Comment: Oh, rats, too replace-happy. Should of course use `arr[i].x` in the caomputation.

Comment: I _hate_ when I do that!  :-)  I've added an alternative to my own answer, which I hope will be easier to understand.

Comment: @AdamLiss, Daneil Thank you. The rectangle is still getting disappear also :)

Comment: @user1234524521 With the corrected code, I don't get any distortion or shrinking noticeable with bare eyes for tens of millions of iterations. If your rectangle still shrinks, there must be something else going on.

Comment: @user1234524521 That rotation code looks correct, but I just had an idea: are the coordinates of a `POINT` perhaps integers? In that case, you'd get shrinking from truncation. You need to work with `double` coordinates, and maybe convert to `int` for display, if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The origin is set to (400, 400), so the rotation takes place around that point.  If you want the object to rotate around the object's center, which is (150, 150), set the origin to that point.

Then, as [Daniel Fischer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1011995/daniel-fischer) noted in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13100199/29157), use the *original* position in the calculations:

```
double old_x = arr[i].x;
double old_y = arr[i].y;

arr[i].x = old_x * cos(angle) - old_y * sin(angle);
arr[i].y = old_x * sin(angle) + old_y * cos(angle);
```

Comment: Thanks. It still is getting small while rotation until it finally disappears.

Answer (score 0):

For each point [rotate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) it by using this matrix:

[image]

that is what you are doing and it is OK.

And translate it by using

[image]

And that what you are doing and that is ok as well.

That is your code with the fixed code, mentioned by the others:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <math.h>
#define ID_TIMER 1

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND , UINT , WPARAM , LPARAM );
void WINAPI Rotate(POINT arr[5]);

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR szCmdLine, int cmdShow)
{
    TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("HelloWin32");
        HWND hWnd;
        MSG msg;
        WNDCLASS wndClass;
        wndClass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
        wndClass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
        wndClass.cbClsExtra = wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
        wndClass.hInstance = hInstance;
        wndClass.hIcon = LoadIcon(0, IDI_APPLICATION);
        wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(0, IDC_ARROW);
        wndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject(1);
        wndClass.lpszMenuName = 0;
        wndClass.lpszClassName = szAppName;

        if (!RegisterClass(&wndClass))
        {
                MessageBox(0, TEXT("Failed to register window class"), TEXT("Error"), MB_OK | MB_DEFBUTTON1 | MB_ICONERROR);
                return 1;
        }
        hWnd = CreateWindow(szAppName, TEXT("Hello World Win32!!"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
        if (!hWnd)
        {
                MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Failed to create the window"), TEXT("Win32 Error"), MB_ICONERROR);
                return 1;
        }
        SetTimer(hWnd, ID_TIMER, 400, NULL);

        ShowWindow(hWnd, cmdShow);
        UpdateWindow(hWnd);

        while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
        {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        return msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM w, LPARAM l)
{
        static HDC hdc;
        static PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        static POINT arr[5];
        static int i;
        static RECT rect;
        switch (message)
        {
        case WM_CREATE:
                GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
                arr[0].x = 200;
                arr[0].y = 100;
                arr[1].x = 200;
                arr[1].y = 200;
                arr[2].x = 100;
                arr[2].y = 200;
                arr[3].x = 100;
                arr[3].y = 100;
                arr[4].x = arr[0].x;
                arr[4].y = arr[0].y;
                return 0;
        case WM_TIMER:
                Rotate(arr);
                InvalidateRect(hWnd, &rect, TRUE);
                return 0;
        case WM_DESTROY:
                KillTimer(hWnd, ID_TIMER);
                PostQuitMessage(0);
                return 0;
        case WM_PAINT:
                hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
                MoveToEx(hdc, arr[0].x, arr[0].y, NULL);
                for (i = 1; i < 5; ++i) LineTo(hdc, arr[i].x, arr[i].y);
                EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
                return 0;
        case WM_SIZE:
                GetClientRect(hWnd, &rect);
                return 0;
        default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, w, l);
        }
}

void WINAPI Rotate(POINT arr[5])
{
        static const POINT origin = { 150, 150 };
        static int i;
        static const double angle = 0.3;
        static const int direction = 1; // 1 or -1

        for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
             POINT temp;
             arr[i].x -= origin.x;
             arr[i].y -= origin.y;
             temp.x = arr[i].x;
             temp.y = arr[i].y;
             arr[i].x = ceil(arr[i].x * cos(angle)) - ceil(direction * arr[i].y * sin(angle));
             arr[i].y = ceil(direction * temp.x * sin(angle))  + ceil(temp.y * cos(angle));
             arr[i].x += origin.x;
             arr[i].y += origin.y;
        }

}
```

**The changes I made:**

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        {
             POINT temp;
             arr[i].x -= origin.x;
             arr[i].y -= origin.y;
             temp.x = arr[i].x;
             temp.y = arr[i].y;
             arr[i].x = ceil(arr[i].x * cos(angle)) - ceil(direction * arr[i].y * sin(angle));
             arr[i].y = ceil(direction * temp.x * sin(angle))  + ceil(temp.y * cos(angle));
             arr[i].x += origin.x;
             arr[i].y += origin.y;
        }
```

while declare the points like that:

```
 arr[0].x = 200;
                arr[0].y = 100;
                arr[1].x = 200;
                arr[1].y = 200;
                arr[2].x = 100;
                arr[2].y = 200;
                arr[3].x = 100;
                arr[3].y = 100;
                arr[4].x = arr[0].x;
                arr[4].y = arr[0].y;
```

***That is a win32 project in visual studio***

**Comment:**

Could be nice solution for people who look for:

***How to rotate a rectangular in win32 application using `WINAPI`***

Comment: I have added the output to the question

Comment: won't the rectangle be getting bigger and bigger now, as it rotates, because of your use of `ceil`? The right solution is to not *represent* your rectangle with `int`s - i.e. `POINT` struct - but to use doubles for representation and calculation, and only for display have them converted to `int`s.

Comment: @WillNess it is better to use round instead... for a long time the expectation is it will remain in the origin length

Comment: that is a wrong solution. the behaviour will be unpredictable, and there's no real reason why to not use the real solution. which is to use doubles representation for points, and translate to ints only for show.

Comment: @WillNess I totally disagree rounding a double before casting it to int is always better!!!!!

Comment: I didn't claim otherwise. you can "translate doubles to ints for show" by rounding. But if you use ints as representation and round the double calculations, the behaviour becomes unpredictable, even if not as drastically as when using ceil/floor.