# Angle of point around certain point

Tags: c++, rotation, geometry, angle

I have done some investigation on rotating a point at a certain angle from certain point and from question: [C++: Rotating a vector around a certain point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620745/c-rotating-a-vector-around-a-certain-point) I have come up with following so far but it is not giving me correct result, can someone please identify the problem

```
const float angle = -90.0;
const float degreePerRadian = 57.2957795;
const float s = sin(angle / degreePerRadian);
const float c = cos(angle / degreePerRadian);
int p1x = 320;
int p1y = 480;
int p2x = 320;
int p2y = 320;

float centerX = (p2x - p1x) / 2 + p1x;
float centerY = (p2y - p1y) / 2 + p1y;
p2x -= centerX;
p2y -= centerY;
double newX = centerX + (p2x * c - p2y * s);
double newY = centerY + (p2x * s + p2y * c);
```

I get: newX = 240 and newY = 400

EDIT:
I have a weird plane though

```
                                |
                                |    ^
                                |    |
                                |
       -------> ^ (320, 480)    |   (y+)
            90° |               |    |
                |               |    |
                |               |
                . (320, 320)    |
                                |
                                |
      --------------------------(0,0)
                <-- (x+) --
```

If and I want to find out 90 degree angle for the point (320, 480) if line falls to the left and to the right

In fact to be more precise the plain is upside down (basically I am using QGraphicsScene so top left is 0,0 and bottom right is width(), height()

```
                (x+) --->
     (0,0) --------------------------
     |
     |
     |      . (320, 320)
     |      |
     |      |
     |      | 90°
     |      . (320, 480)----------
     |
     |
(y+) |
     |
     |
```

Comment: Are you using values in radians? As far as i remeber most sin/cos functions expect them in radians.

Comment: @Losiowaty Ok so if I change it from radian to degrees i get (-160, 2.87183e-07)

Comment: No, radians are GOOD :) That was just a first thing to ask that came to mind.

Comment: This should help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2259476/rotating-a-point-about-another-point-2d

Comment: Nope that didnt help, http://pastebin.com/LUFyjCae here is the code

Answer (score 1):

Your 16th line of code from link is incorrect. It should be:

double newY = centerY + (p2x * s **+** p2y * c);